# Windows vs. Window-7 tags (OS)

Tags: discussion, tags

It's no big deal, but the [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag of [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28291/quickest-method-to-transfer-a-couple-files-between-windows-and-android) was just changed to be [windows-7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7).  I performed a rollback.

Although the question requires Windows 7 compatible software, there isn't anything special about the question that makes it Windows 7 specific.  Thus, it seems like the [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag is more appropriate.

My understanding is that if a question asks for recommendations that will *only* work on a specific OS version, we use the tag for that version.  When the recommendations do not require functionality only in a specific OS version, but must be compatible with a certain version, we use the most generic tag for that OS, and mention which versions with which is must be compatible within the text.

See also: [How specific should the OS tag be?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-specific-should-the-os-tag-be)

Answer (score 1):

Newer than the linked Meta discussion ([How specific should the OS tag be?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-specific-should-the-os-tag-be)) is this one: [How to handle OS tags](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/how-to-handle-os-tags) (and FWIW, the [highest-voted answer in *How specific should the OS tag be?*](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/90/60) seems to argue against having version-specific OS tags).

There I have posted [the only answer (as of now)](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2320/60), which currently has a score of 5 (+6/-1).

In this answer I suggested that *if* we want to keep the version-specific Windows tags (which I’m not a fan of), they should be used if OP requires this Windows version, no matter if software from the requested "category" typically would run on other Windows version, too.

So according to that answer, [the edit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19336) would be appropriate: You *require* the software to run on Windows 7, so it gets tagged with [windows-7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7).

Comment: It's clear that we need a Usability Study for tags.  How are they actually used?  More importantly, what tasks do users want to perform with them?